# Como verificar se existe um número em diversos campos de uma tabela

Tags: sql-server, query, select

Tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados SQLServer que simula uma cartela de bingo. No total são 25 campos que representam a cartela: `n1, n2, n3, ..., n25`

Digamos que eu tenha sorteado os números 5, 28 e 67, como eu faço um select pra saber se a cartela atual tem esses números nos campos que citei acima?

Preciso de algo +- assim `select * from cartelas where n1, n2, n3..., n25 in [5, 28, 67]`

Sei que é pedir demais, mas o resultado teria que ser semelhante a:

`Cartela | Acertos
       1 |       3
       2 |       3
       3 |       2
       4 |       1
       5 |       1
       6 |       1`

Nem sei se é possível algo do tipo apenas usando select, mas, fico aguardando alguma sugestão.

Comment: Me parece que a forma mais simples é através do uso de mapa de bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o código abaixo:

```
select b.*, s.cnt
from cartela b cross apply
    (select count(*) as cnt
        from (values (n1), (n2), (n3), (n4), (n5), (n6), (n7), (n8), (n9), (n10), (n11), (n12), (n13), (n14), (n15), (n16), (n17), (n18), (n19), (n20), (n21), (n22), (n23), (n24), (n25)) v(n)
        where n in (5, 28, 67)
        ) s
order by s.cnt desc
```